# How to reset a seed value

Tags: r

Is there any way to remove the seed value? I just ran a sample code as below

```
set.seed(912)
sample(10)
```

I got below result.

```
[1]  5  8  2 10  9  3  4  7  1  6
```

Now how do I stop the seed value. I closed my R session without saving and ran the same code as above after re-opening and got the result in same sequence.

I got below code from one of the questions related to seed but that also didn't work.

```
set.seed(Sys.time())
```

Comment: `?set` says something about `.Random.seed`, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Try `set.seed(seed = NULL); sample(10)` ("If called with seed = NULL it re-initializes (see ‘Note’) as if no seed had yet been set.")

Comment: @docendodiscimus I ran the same code `set.seed(seed = NULL)` and then `set.seed(912); sample(10)` but again I got the same sequence `[1]  5  8  2 10  9  3  4  7  1  6`

Comment: I am not sure, what do you mean by `remove`. Try this sequence of execution `set.seed(912); sample(10); sample(10)`. The first and second output are different.

Comment: @RonakShah I mean I want to reset the seed or I don't want any seed value to exist. After resetting the seed when i run the `set.seed(912); sample(10)` I want a new set of values.

Comment: Everytime you run `set.seed(912); sample(10)`, you'll get the same values. That is for what `seed` values are. You run it on any system on any environment. `set.seed(912); sample(10)` would give you the same values. For different results you need different `seed` value. `set.seed(913); sample(10)` .

Comment: @RonakShah You mean to say there is no way to reset or nullify the seed value that is already stored?

Comment: @Yash not that I am aware of.

Comment: Maybe `# set.seed(912)` ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is the script which comes from the help menu - i found it in this post: [Questions about set.seed() in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10910698/questions-about-set-seed-in-r)

```
rm(.Random.seed, envir=globalenv())
```

Here's an example:

```
> set.seed(912)
> rm(.Random.seed, envir=globalenv())
> sample(10)
 [1]  1  8  2 10  3  4  6  7  9  5
> set.seed(912)
> rm(.Random.seed, envir=globalenv())
> sample(10)
 [1]  2  9  3  4 10  7  6  8  1  5
> set.seed(912)
> rm(.Random.seed, envir=globalenv())
> sample(10)
 [1]  3 10  7  8  5  2  1  4  9  6
```

Hope this helps.

You could always just execute the sample(10) without setting the seed to return different samples if you are not concerned with setting a seed.

Comment: If you set again the same seed you will get the same result on sample, if after rm(....) you don't set.seed then you will get a different sample

Comment: Perfect solution to my problem, thank you!!!